# Probability of winning 2nd trial if 1st trial is different?

Tags: probability, statistics

My company is running a contest right now where a winner is chosen from two pools: Pool A might have $n$ entries and Pool B might have $m$ entries. One person is chosen from Pool A and one person is chosen from Pool B, and then one is chosen from either of those two people.

For sake of example, say $n = 20$, $m = 5$. How do I determine the final probability of winning the entire contest? It's not just a $1/25$ chance, is it? Pool A winner has a $1/20$ chance, Pool B winner has a $1/5$ chance, and then the winner between the pool winners is $1/2$, how do I find the probability of the winner between the two pools?

Is it perhaps if you were in Pool A, you have a $(1/20 * 1/2)$ or $(1/5 * 1/2)$ for Pool B?

Comment: Of course a person from group $B$ has a much greater chance of winning, but a randomly selected person has a much lower chance of being in group $B$...these effects cancel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For someone in group A to win, they have to be drawn, which has chance $\frac 1n$, then be chosen, which has chance $\frac 12$. The chance of both events is the product. In your example, people in group B have a much higher chance than people in group A.

Comment: If group $n$ has 20 people and group $m$ has 5 people, the probability of a person who ends up in group $m$ is 1/10. But lets add another person to group $n$: how is it the odds don't change for that person in group $m$ even though the total pool of people increases?

Comment: Adding people to group $n$ does not change the chance of each person in group $m$ winning.  As you say, it stays $\frac 1{10}$.  The five of them share the $\frac 12$ chance their group is picked. The people in group $n$ share the $\frac 12$ chance *their* group is picked, and each gets a smaller share if people are added.  If there is only one person in group $m$, s/he has $\frac 12$ chance of winning regardless of how many are in the other group.

Answer (score 1):

I interpret the question to be:  Given that you select a person uniformly at random from the pool of $n+m$ candidates, what is the probability that your selected person will win.

The eventual winner has to win two contests:  the one for their pool, and then the over all contest.  Specifically, there are two independent paths to victory:

Path I:  Be in group $A$ (probability = $\frac n{n+m}$). Win group $A$ (probability $\frac 1n$).  Win the final contest (probability =$\frac 12$).  Thus $$\frac n{n+m}\times \frac 1n\times \frac 12=\frac 1{2(n+m)}$$

Path II:  Be in group $B$ (probability = $\frac m{n+m}$). Win group $B$ (probability $\frac 1m$).  Win the final contest (probability =$\frac 12$).  Thus $$\frac m{n+m}\times \frac 1m\times \frac 12=\frac 1{2(n+m)}$$

Thus, while it is certainly true that a person in the smaller group has a higher chance of winning, a randomly selected person has a much lower probability of being from the smaller group...and these two effects exactly cancel out.  In the end, the answer really is just $\boxed {\frac 1{n+m}}$

Comment: The question explicitly states "One person is chosen from Pool A and one person is chosen from Pool B, and then one is chosen from either of those two people."

Comment: @trueblueanil  Yes...but the OP also asks "How do I determine the final probability of winning the entire contest?".   And the discussion which follows suggests that they are looking for a single number...which I think has to have the interpretation I give.  I agree it isn't clear, which is why I made my interpretation explicit.  Of course, if the OP means something else, they should say so.

Comment: Well, you have read the mind of OP better ! :)

Comment: @trueblueanil  It's a good question I think...on the one hand, it's trivial.  Nothing distinguishes the people initially, so of course the answer is the same for all.  On the other hand, it certainly feels like you broke the symmetry when you divided the pool into uneven groups.  Anyway, I think a pure appeal to symmetry is not entirely convincing.  figured it was a worth an explicit computation.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is "how do I find the probability of the winner between the two pools?", the answer is simply $\frac12$, as the winner is decided between $2$ people, one each from pool $A$ and pool $B.$

If your question, say, is what is P(a *particular* person from pool $A$ wins), $Pr=\frac1{20}\cdot\frac12$ for the example with $n=20, m=5$

and P(a *particular* person from pool $B$ wins) $=\frac15\cdot\frac12$,
as you have computed at the end of your question.